# Grouping by each value of a column based on the categories of a list they fall into

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Today has been quite challenging so I can't think of any new ideas anymore so the solution to this question may be quite obvious to you. I have a very simple data frame like bellow:

```
structure(list(user_id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 106, 107, 
111), phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203, 
4030204, 4030205, 4030203), id = 1:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

and also a list:

```
list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), 6, 7)
```

I want to group each value in `id` column of my data frame based on the category they fall into of elements of the list preferably with `purrr` package functions. So the desired output is something like this:

```
grp <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Thank you very much in advance and learning from/ beside you guys has been a great honor of my life.

Sincerely Yours

Anoushiravan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case-I** when the list is unnamed

```r
df <- structure(list(user_id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 106, 107,
                           111), phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203,
                                                  4030204, 4030205, 4030203), id = 1:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                             -8L))
lst <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), 6, 7)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(GRP = map(id, \(xy) seq_along(lst)[map_lgl(lst, ~ xy %in% .x)]))
#>   user_id phone_number id GRP
#> 1     101      4030201  1   1
#> 2     102      4030201  2   1
#> 3     102      4030202  3   1
#> 4     103      4030202  4   1
#> 5     103      4030203  5   1
#> 6     106      4030204  6   2
#> 7     107      4030205  7   3
#> 8     111      4030203  8   1
```

---

**Case-II** when the list is named

```r
df <- structure(list(user_id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 106, 107,
                           111), phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203,
                                                  4030204, 4030205, 4030203), id = 1:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                             -8L))
lst <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), b = 6, c = 7)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(GRP = map(id, \(xy) names(lst)[map_lgl(lst, ~ xy %in% .x)]))
#>   user_id phone_number id GRP
#> 1     101      4030201  1   a
#> 2     102      4030201  2   a
#> 3     102      4030202  3   a
#> 4     103      4030202  4   a
#> 5     103      4030203  5   a
#> 6     106      4030204  6   b
#> 7     107      4030205  7   c
#> 8     111      4030203  8   a
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

One option involving `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
    mutate(grp = imap(lst, ~ .y * (id %in% .x)) %>% reduce(`+`))

  user_id phone_number id grp
1     101      4030201  1   1
2     102      4030201  2   1
3     102      4030202  3   1
4     103      4030202  4   1
5     103      4030203  5   1
6     106      4030204  6   2
7     107      4030205  7   3
8     111      4030203  8   1
```

Comment: I edited my answer to suit both the cases. :)